# forwarding two ports for a minecraft server

Tags: linux, networking, port

We have a Minecraft server running on Ubuntu Server 20.04. We are using GeyserMC https://geysermc.org/
so that our Minecraft server can be cross-platform. Java edition connects over port 25565, and bedrock edition 19132.
We forwarded both ports on the router already.
We were able to connect over port 25565, but we can't connect over 19132.

We put this in /etc/netplan/config.yaml:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    enp3s25:
        dhcp4: no
    addresses: [192.168.254.25/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.254.254
        nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Do we need to add another network interface for the second port to work?
I hardly know anything about networking...

Comment: This question might be better for gaming.stackexchange.com. Just to make sure, is port 19132 forwarded as UDP or TCP on your router?

Comment: Is the server listening on port 19132? Confirm with `netstat -atulpn | grep 19132`

Comment: @Thegs what is UDP and TCP?

Comment: @tommyokie They are two different protocols for network communication. I can't really explain in comments, so at the risk of answering in comments most likely what is going on is your router by default forwards the TCP port, while a Bedrock server communicates on UDP port 19132. Most consumer routers I've seen default to TCP as the protocol to forward, so I would check your configuration to make sure that port 19132 is being forwarded as UDP, not TCP.

Comment: @Thegs alright ill try that

Comment: @Thegs thank you sooo much, that was the problem

Comment: @tommyokie Great! I'll write up an answer to post then

Answer (score 1):

Within today's Internet Protocol (IP) model of networking, there are two primary means of communicating between two hosts: the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) and the User Datagram Protocol (UDP). There are many more, but we're sticking to basics here.

The easiest distinction between TCP and UDP is that TCP has a handshake between the two hosts acknowledging that they have established communication and have received the network packets that the other host has sent. This provides error checking and correction, as the receiving host will be aware if packets are lost along the way and can request the sending host to resend those packets. However, this comes at a loss of performance, as more compute and bandwidth is required to send data.

UDP on the otherhand does not validate that the packets have been received (or were received in order). Rather, UDP focuses on performance of network interfaces; it is possible to receive more data with less computing effort required using UDP.

What does this have to do with Minecraft? Since it's inception, the Java edition of Minecraft Server has communicated over TCP port 25565. However, with the release of the Bedrock edition, Microsoft decided to change the protocol this server edition would use to *UDP* port 19132, most likely looking to take advantage of the performance benefits UDP has to offer. This complicates opening the server up to public connections, however, because consumer routers tend to default to forwarding a TCP port simply because that is what most applications we would forward over our router would use.

As a result, switching the protocol forwarded from TCP to UDP in your router will permit client connections to the Bedrock-facing side of your Minecraft server.

Comment: This is all a very basic explanation of what was going on and why, the 10,000' overview if you will.